# Apache NetBeans Update Center URL

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-15

I'm using NetBeans since release 4.0 and so I'm re-using my configuration from upgrade to upgrade. Unfortunately that means, that newer default settings aren't updated, for example the URL of the plugin portal. As the old one on netbeans.org is closed now, I have to download all plugins one-by-one and to install them manually.

On https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/ there are tons of plugins but I can't figure out, where the corresponding .gz file is, so that the IDE can load them by itself. The given "https://netbeans.apache.org/nb/plugins/15/catalog.xml.gz" contains lousy 3 modules only.

Comment: That's a topic that's discussed on the mailing list: https://lists.apache.org/thread/yb3smkz109ownxlk81t61gvgzl6479j3 So: no fault on  your side that you see so few plugins.

Comment: That means, the NB 15 plugin portal really contains only that few plugins? Pity.